# Why does this doesn't work in shift-right array

Tags: java, arrays, shift

I've been answering codility exercises since yesterday. One of the problems is shifting the array to the right. Now, I don't understand why this code that I tried didn't work, while the one that I saw in google worked.

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
        int[] rotatedA = new int[A.length];
        if(K == 0) {
            rotatedA = A;
        } else {
            while(K > 0) {
                int last = A[A.length-1];
                for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
                    rotatedA[i] = A[i-1];
                }
                rotatedA[0] = last;
                A = rotatedA;
                K--;
            }
        }
        return rotatedA;
    }
```

Theoretically, I believe that is correct, however, the answer seemed weird:

Example test:    ([3, 8, 9, 7, 6], 3)
WRONG ANSWER  (got [6, 7, 7, 7, 7] expected [9, 7, 6, 3, 8])

Example test:    ([0, 0, 0], 1)
OK

Example test:    ([1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
WRONG ANSWER  (got [3, 4, 4, 4] expected [1, 2, 3, 4])

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this assignment in your loop:

```
A = rotatedA;
```

After one iteration, your source and target array are the same object.

To fix it, instead of assigning, you would have to copy the values from your target array back to your source array. This is however, a pretty inefficient solution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it won't work with or without that line due to `rotatedA[i] = A[i-1];`. OP first needs to copy the values of array `A` into `rotatedA`, and then start operating on `rotatedA` only.